# Get the parameter in form action

Tags: html, regex, parsing

I have parsed the html page to get following form action values

```
string val = action="?bID=5&amp;WorkID=20007&amp;LanguageAbbreviation=en_US&amp;rootMenu=&amp;isTerm=False"
```

now I want to get the 20007 of WorkID out of this action, so I need to use RegEx, or is there any splitting method in C# to achieve it fast?

Comment: var workId =val.Split("&")[1].Replace("WorkID","");

Comment: Is that a string what u got?

Comment: `string val = 'action="?bID=5&WorkID=20007&LanguageAbbreviation=en_US&rootMenu=&isTerm=False"'`

Comment: yes the "action=.....isTerm=False" is a string that I got, now I want to get the WorkID @VamsiKrishna

Comment: @Rex : for your code I got the result as following: amp;=20007

Comment: or with regex http://regex101.com/r/xN8oD9 get the value in second match group

Comment: try this regex (\?|\&)([^=]+)\=([^&]+)

Comment: change that to var workId =val.Split("&amp;")[1].Replace("WorkID","");

Comment: That regex gives you all the params list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var val = 'action="?bID=5&amp;WorkID=20007&amp;LanguageAbbreviation=en_US&amp;rootMenu=&amp;isTerm=False"'
val = val.replace(/\&amp;/g, ",")
val = val.replace("action=\"?", "")
val = val.replace(/\"/g, "")
var values = val.split(",")
var obj = {}

for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
   var item = values[i].split("=")
   obj[item[0]] = item[1]
}
console.log(obj.WorkID) // 20007 --this will have required value
```

here obj will have all value from action